# Unity with qualcomm integration to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, unity-game-engine

I am trying to integrate unity to eclipse (more precise unity with qualcomm to eclipse) for android development. I followed the steps from [here](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Integrating%20Unity%20With%20Eclipse.html) probably 10 times already and still have some features not to be working (Camera issues).

I am building an app which combines unity with [qualcomm](https://ar.qualcomm.at/qdevnet/sdk). I need a simple android development environment as well, so my idea is to make a part of it in unity and port to eclipse for further development.
If I build and launch my app straight from Unity everything works well: ARCamera, simple Camera and all other features work as intended. If I export the program to eclipse and launch it from there I get a black window on ARCamera and blue window if I change the view to simple Camera.

Does anyone has a clue what am I doing wrong?

- If I am using qualcomm in eclipse (no unity) everything works
- If I am using qualcomm in unity (no eclipse) everything works
- If I try to export qualcomm with unity to eclipse - camera doesn't work

I am using HTC Nexus One

Comment: Could you post the error you get? I managed to solve this issue with the Metaio engine, not with the QCar, I had to import the .jar from metaio into the Eclipse project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is still interested what was the problem, the links above are missing few things:

1. Add classes.jar, QCAR.jar, and QCARUnityPlayer.jar to your custom Android project.
2. Copy config.xml and qcar-resources.dat from the StagingArea/raw/QCAR folder to the new project's assets folder.
3. Copy the AndroidManifest.xml file from the StagingArea to your new project as well.
4. Instead of extending PlayerActivity in your class, extend QCARPlayerActivity

By doing those things I managed to get it work.

Comment: Besides, unity 3.5 integration to eclipse is broken...So you have to use earlier versions of unity or wait for the next release and hope that it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Mindaugai, do you have permissions properly set in the Manifest after you export to Eclipse? I'm refering to these:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="true" />
```

You might also need this one:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="true" />
```

Comment: Vytautai, I have all the permissions set correctly. I have figured out what was the problem but haven't updated the thread. If interested see my next post.

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
*Unity v. 1.5
*Vuforia SDK 1.5.9
*Android SDK 4.0
```

and I made it working, so either, the integration has been fixed or my slightly different approach just worked.

Here are steps I did:

1. Follow the integration instruction from [here](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Manual/Android-Integrating%20Unity%20With%20Eclipse.html)
2. In the library project add `QCAR.jar` and `QCARUnityPlayer.jar` from `./plugins` to  the build path
3. Make sure that those libraries are exported by checking proper checkboxes in `Project properties > Java build path > Order and Export`
4. Copy `AndroidManifest.xml` from the lib project to your custom project
5. Modify `AndroidManifest.xml` to link to your custom Activity that extends `QCARPlayerActivity`

It should work now.

Tips&Hints

If you are getting an error that says: `error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|
 mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen').`
just switch to higher SDK (I used 4.0 but 3.2 should work as well).